# Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) + Matlab

Tags: matlab, least-squares

Please help me to solve the equation with Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) method.

Given two same length vectors:


$x=(x_{1} , ... , x_{n})$

$y=(y_{1} , ... , y_{n})$


**1) Find coefficients **a,b,c** for:**

$y_{i} = ax_{i}^2 + bx_{i} + c$

such that: $$\int_0^1 (ax^2+bx+c) \,dx= 0$$

**2) Solve it with Matlab** 

I'll be very grateful for your help!

**My way:**
I tried something like this:

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 ax_{1}^2+bx_{1}+c &= y_{1} \\ ...\\
 ax_{n}^2+bx_{n}+c &= y_{n}
\end{aligned}\right.
$

After that:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      x_{1}^2&x_{1}&1\\
      x_{2}^2&x_{2}&1\\...\\
      x_{n}^2&x_{n}&1\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[
\begin{array}{}
      a\\
      b\\c\\
    \end{array}
\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{}
      y_{1}\\
      y_{2}\\...\\y_{n}
    \end{array}
\right]$$

In Matlab:

M= [x.^2    x    ones(length(x),1)];}

U = M\Y  or U = pinv(M)*Y;

And after that:

U(1) = a;
U(2) = b;
U(3) = c;

But I don't understand why I need an Integral?

Comment: I added my way to solve it.

Comment: Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow David's suggestion. As K. Miller mentioned, the integral gives you a constraint, or a relationship between the three coefficients. You can find

$$c=-\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{1}{2}b$$
and plug this $c$ into your fitting equation.

This gives you
$$y_i=ax_i^2+bx_i-\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{1}{2}b\\
=a(x_i^2-\frac{1}{3})+b(x_i-\frac{1}{2})$$

Now using $x_i^2-\frac{1}{3}$ and $x_i-\frac{1}{2}$ as values in your matrix, you can find the coefficients $a$ and $b$. $c$ is then determined by the first equation obtained by that integral.

Comment: Thank you! Now it clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you wrote it seems to me that the integral equation is imposing a constraint on your least squares solution. In order to satisfy this constraint the coefficients $a, b, c$ must satisfy the equation

$$
2a + 3b + 6c = 0,
$$

that is, solutions must lie on the plane through the origin with normal vector $(2,3,6)$. Your Matlab solution is correct in the unconstrained case, but it doesn't work in the constrained case since it finds the best solution over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am not sure what Matlab toolboxes you have access to, but you may want to look at lsqlin, which solves constrained linear least-squares problems.

Comment: You can use your condition to rewrite the quadratic equation as $y=(-3/2 x^2+x)a+(-3x^2+1)b$, and solve for just $b$ and $c$ using `N = [-3/2*xi.^2+xi -3*xi.^2+1];` and then `V = N\yi`, with the approximated $y$'s being given by `V.'*[-3/2*x.^2+x;-3*x.^2+1]`.

Comment: Could you explain please how did you get this equation for y? Where is a coefficient c?